# How to get a list of all open graph actions created by friends in an app via the graph api

Tags: android-activity, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a canvas app that creates open graph actions.  In the left sidebar, I'd like to display the following:

**My Actions**

- Action ME.3
- Action ME.2
- Action ME.1

**Friends' Actions**

- Action F1.2
- Action F2.1
- Action F1.2
- Action F3.1

The first part is easy (get my actions)

```
FB.api(
   /me/ACTION?limit=10,
   get,
   ...
```

Getting the second part (friends' actions) is not so simple

First, get friends who are app users (FQL query is the only efficient way), Second, loop through friends and get actions

```
FB.api(
    {    
     method:'fql.query',
     query: 'SELECT uid,username, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user=1'
    },
    function(friends) {
        if (friends && friends.length) {
           for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
               FB.api(
                    '/'+ friends[i].uid + '/ACTION?limit=10',
                    'get',
                     ...
```

And since you get back data from each friend query individually

```
Add each action to an array, sort by date (newest first) and return the first 10
```

Is there really no other way?  Nothing like

```
/me/friends/ACTION?limit=10
```

or possibly a FQL query against an undocumented app_actions table?